# Translated default values when using paragraphs

Tags: paragraphs

I've set default values for a paragraph field for each language on my site, but when creating language pages, it only ever shows the english version.

I can set the default value manually by setting `$element['subform']['field_component_about_us_text']['widget']['0']['#default_value'] = "Default Text";` within `publication_field_widget_form_alter` , but I'm not able to get the translated default values from the paragraph definition.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Thanks,

Luca